# What are the possible reasonable meanings of "Love thy neighbor"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, translation, parashas-kedoshim

1. What are the original Hebrew words for "love", "thy", "neighbor", "as", "you", "love", "yourself" in "love thy neighbor as you love your self"?
2. What's the transliteration of those words in English (in case you
   answer the first with Hebrew letters)?
3. What are the potential reasonable translations of those words?
4. What are the possible reasonable meanings of those words?

Sorry for making 4 question marks, but I am sure everyone can see that it's essentially one question. I am just guiding the kind of detailed explanation I want to see.

**Motivation:** Many Jews seem to think that it's the second most important commandment in Torah.

- English speaking Christians think it means to be "altruist" to "those
  who live near you". Actually that's literally what "love your
  neighbor" means in English.
- Wikipedia says that Jews interpret that to mean being "fair" to
  "fellow Jews".
- Some gnostic gospel claims that it means you need to love
  your "friends," namely those who have been kind to you. It's more of
  advice than a good deed.
- Indonesians translate that as something along "love your fellow
  humans" (kasihilah sesamamu manusia seperti dirimu sendiri) which literally implies we have to love members of the same species as us (homo sapiens). That is the actual Indonesian translation of the Bible phrase.

Thus, this is supposedly the second most important commandment and yet everyone interprets it differently to a pretty substantial degree.

So I simply want to know more about what are all the reasonable meanings and perhaps I can have a better "guess" of what it must truly mean.

Obviously, since I'm asking on this site, I seek the Jewish interpretations.

Comment: Cf. the toldos aharon on that pasuk (mikraot gedolot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase comes from [Leviticus 19:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0319.htm#18):

> וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ
>   Ve-Ah-Hahv-TA Le-Ray-Ah-CHA Ka-MOE-Cha

It is three words in Hebrew:

- And you should love
- Your fellow
- Like yourself

Comment: Thanks. Can you split the transliteration into words... So Veahhahvta is one word which mean "and you should love"? Notice the link you gave me use the word "neighbor" instead of "friend"

Comment: @JimThio Exactly. I wrote the transliteration that way to be clear about the proper syllables and emphasis.

Comment: So one hebrew word with 4 letters correspond to 4 english words? Hebrew must be very succinct.

Comment: @JimThio Yes. It doesn't mean neighbor like 'next door neighbor' but it also doesn't mean friend like 'best friend'. I guess it's more like 'comrad'. If someone else has a better English word please suggest it.

Comment: @JimThio Hebrew is an [Abjad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad). (BTW the Hebrew words are read right to left.)

Comment: Not like yourself. As yourself.

Comment: oh ya. I update my question. as you love your self.

Comment: That rayah or reeh seems to be the only word I recognize. It means comrade isn't it? Without the commie connotation it could be something like business partners that you've gone through making profit together (or fight someone together).

Comment: Looks to me this topic won't fit one question. I'll live it to one for now and select the only answer (though very unclear) as the answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've sometimes seen "your fellow" (don't remember where), which like "comrad" avoids some of the ambiguities of "friend".

Comment: what's the different between fellow, friends, and comrads and which one the word reeh means closest too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I like it.

Comment: Note: The prefix LE of le-reyacha means "to," IOW "you should love ***to*** your fellow/comrade/friend like yourself." I think that the meaning is that it is not referring to the emotion of love, but to actions of love.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fellow hmm... not even sure what fellow really means. Your "equal"? Partner? comrade seems to make more sense.

Comment: Thanks Dov. So love here means somewhere along being profitable, kind, or useful to your comrade?

Comment: @JimThio I believe so. Or as Hillel of the Talmud put it, "that which is hateful to you, do not do to your friend."

Comment: @DovF Interesting point. I can't search now, but offhand do you know of other instances where the root A.H.B takes a 'to' instead of a standard direct object (such as Veahavta **ET** Hashem Elokecha...)?

Comment: @DoubleAA After quickly skimming through the concordance the only similar instance I noticed was from the same chapter - about loving converts in verse 34 - "and you should love 'to' him like yourself."

Comment: @DovF Very parallel. It still sounds funny to me as an intransitive verb.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wrote this a long time ago: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/a-question-about-being-self-centered/page/2#post-288105

Comment: that's strange, is that pasuk written in your sefer torah? i hope so.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I hope so too. <confused>

Comment: @DoubleAA - The literal translation is certainly "to love", but would the version "you  shall take care of your neighbor as of yourself" be admissible? I have read in some explanatory comments of the precept, that its meaning is: the life, the honor and the assets of  your neighbor are dear to you like yours. " Now, the  verb "to love" lends itself to multiple meanings and misunderstandings, while the expression" taking care of "seems to me more in keeping with the intrinsic significance of the commandment.